# Do I need -moz- and -webkit- in an angular project or does angular compile the css to a format readable by any browser?

Tags: css, angular, vendor-prefix, angular-compiler

I know Angular compiles code and serves it as html, javascript and css. So my question is: Do I need -moz- and -webkit- in an angular project or does angular compile the css to a format readable by any browser?

Comment: I don't believe so, I have seen people suggest adding [autoprefixer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autoprefixer) to webpack.

Comment: @Drenai Does React take care of that too? Or does someone need an extra library when using react?

Comment: Look in the file `.browserslistrc` and you'll see precisely what browsers are supported.